# How to save data from Ext.FormPanel to server?

Tags: java, javascript, extjs

I have a store and a `FormPanel`. I want to send data from the `FormPanel` to a server:

```
 var store_form=null;
 store_form = new Ext.data.Store({                
        url: url_servlet+"kadastr_zemform.jsp",
        reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({
        totalProperty: "results", 
        record: "contact",
                        fields: [
       ]}),

    });    

});
store_form.load();
```

Panel

```
var podform = new Ext.FormPanel({
    labelAlign: 'left',
    id: 'tab_6',
    frame:true,
    title: 'Договоры подряда',
    bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
    width: 600,
            reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({}),
    listeners: {
        'activate' :  function(pod_form,records,options) {
        console.log("store:"+store_form);
        this.loaded = true;
        //alert("loaded");
        //console.log(store.getAt(0));
        var record = store_form.getAt(0);
        podform.getForm().loadRecord(record);
        }
    },
            fields[]
 });

podform.addButton({
    text: 'Submit',
    //disabled:true,
    handler: function(){
    podform.getForm().submit({url:url_servlet+'submit.jsp', waitMsg:'Saving Data...', submitEmptyText: false});
    }
});
```

In firebug I can see that nothing is sent to the server. What am I doing wrong?
Another question: what can I do on the server side to get this data?

**UPDATE**

I forgot to add `XMLReader` to form. But nothing has changed.

**UPDATE2**

Now parameters are sent to the server:[image]
But I am getting an error:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error

...ayer=a;this.activate()}else{this.layer=a}},setTargets:function(b){this.targets=[...
```

Comment: Sorry i write something wrong in last update. I get error on client side not in jsp(

Comment: Hi, you can send an Ajax request to the from the javascript as, **Ext.Ajax.Request({})**

with your form panel elements as the request parameters. 

and at server side you can use **Servlets** and do the necessary logic and sent back the response...

Comment: I gonna use getFieldValues() method for this?

Comment: I tried to do this but firebug says that i send  `[object Object]` to server.

Comment: Now all works. i dont know why i get errors before but now all fine. I just do like in this example http://examples.extjs.eu/formloadsubmit.html .